# matplotlib for loop not plotting my first value due to sub plot append?

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I have been trying to plot time series weather data which has wind speed values and split them by sub plots on a monthly basis. I have created a for loop to use the meteogram function however have found that the first month January will not plot even when I try and debug. I think it's a figure calling issue but I am quite new and don't really understand what the issue is. I think it's because I'm calling the function which is creating the plot where as I should be creating the plot from within the bottom lines.

I was expecting an output of 12 tables corresponding to each month of the year. Instead I only get months 02 - 12.

Additionally I am not able to save the entire figure as a subplot.

```
# Original 
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from metpy.calc import dewpoint_from_relative_humidity
from metpy.cbook import get_test_data
from metpy.units import units

# Make meteogram plot
class Meteogram:
    """ Plot a time series of meteorological datafrom a particular station as a
    meteogram with standard variables to visualize, including thermodynamic,
    kinematic, and pressure. The functions below control the plotting of each
    variable.
    TO DO: Make the subplot creation dynamic so the number of rows is not
    static as it is currently. """

    def __init__(self, fig, dates, probeid, time=None, axis=0):
        """
        Required input:
            fig: figure object
            dates: array of dates corresponding to the data
            probeid: ID of the station
        Optional Input:
            time: Time the data is to be plotted
            axis: number that controls the new axis to be plotted (FOR FUTURE)
        """
        if not time:
            time = dt.datetime.utcnow()
            
        self.start = starttime
        self.fig = fig
        self.end = endtime
        self.axis_num = 1
        self.dates = mpl.dates.date2num(dates)
        #self.time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M UTC')
        #self.title = f'Latest Ob Time: {self.time}\nProbe ID: {probeid}'

    def plot_winds(self, ws, wd, wsmax, plot_range=None):
        """
        Required input:
            ws: Wind speeds (knots)
            wd: Wind direction (degrees)
            wsmax: Wind gust (knots)
        Optional Input:
            plot_range: Data range for making figure (list of (min,max,step))
        """
        # PLOT WIND SPEED AND WIND DIRECTION
        self.ax1 = fig.add_subplot()
        ln1 = self.ax1.plot(self.dates, ws, label='Wind Speed')
        self.ax1.fill_between(self.dates, ws, 0)
        self.ax1.set_xlim(self.start, self.end)
        if not plot_range:
            plot_range = [0, 30, 1]
        self.ax1.set_ylabel('Wind Speed (knots)', multialignment='center')
        self.ax1.set_ylim(plot_range[0], plot_range[1], plot_range[2])
        self.ax1.grid(b=True, which='major', axis='y', color='k', linestyle='-',
                      linewidth=0.5)
        ln2 = self.ax1.plot(self.dates, wsmax, '.r', label='Gust')

        ax7 = self.ax1.twinx()
        ln3 = ax7.plot(self.dates, wd, '.k', linewidth=0.1, label='Wind Direction')
        
        ax7.set_ylabel('Wind\nDirection\n(degrees)', multialignment='center')
        ax7.set_ylim(0, 360)
        #ax7.set_yticks(90,45,0)
            
        lines = ln1 + ln2 + ln3
        labs = [line.get_label() for line in lines]
        ax7.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d'))
        ax7.legend(lines, labs, loc='center', bbox_to_anchor=(.9, -0.25), ncol=3, prop={'size': 12})


# ID For Plotting on Meteogram
probe_id = 'SOCA'

from calendar import monthrange
year = 2019

# I think the issue is in here somwhere 

for months in range(1, 13):
    
    a = monthrange(year, months)

    endtime = dt.datetime(2019, months, a[-1], 0, 0)
    starttime = dt.datetime(2019, months, 1, 0, 0)

    df_new = df[(df['ICAO'] == probe_id) & (df['month'] == months)]
    df_new['wind_speed'] = pd.to_numeric(df_new['wind_speed'], errors='coerce')
    df_new['wind_dir'] = pd.to_numeric(df_new['wind_dir'], errors='coerce')
    df_new['wind_gust'] = pd.to_numeric(df_new['wind_gust'], errors='coerce')
    df_new['temp'] = pd.to_numeric(df_new['temp'], errors='coerce')
    df_new['dewpt'] = pd.to_numeric(df_new['dewpt'], errors='coerce')
    df_new['press'] = pd.to_numeric(df_new['press'], errors='coerce')
    df_new['wind_gust'] = df_new['wind_gust'].fillna(0)

    #& (df['month'] == month) & (df['hour'] < 8) & (df['hour'] > 4)]

    meteogram = Meteogram(fig, df_new['datetime'], probe_id)
    meteogram.plot_winds(df_new['wind_speed'], df_new['wind_dir'], df_new['wind_gust'])
    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))   

plt.savefig('test.png')
```

----- Update

```
# Original 
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from metpy.calc import dewpoint_from_relative_humidity
from metpy.cbook import get_test_data
from metpy.units import units

# Make meteogram plot
class Meteogram:
    """ Plot a time series of meteorological datafrom a particular station as a
    meteogram with standard variables to visualize, including thermodynamic,
    kinematic, and pressure. The functions below control the plotting of each
    variable.
    TO DO: Make the subplot creation dynamic so the number of rows is not
    static as it is currently. """

    def __init__(self, fig, dates, probeid, time=None, axis=0):
        """
        Required input:
            fig: figure object
            dates: array of dates corresponding to the data
            probeid: ID of the station
        Optional Input:
            time: Time the data is to be plotted
            axis: number that controls the new axis to be plotted (FOR FUTURE)
        """
        if not time:
            time = dt.datetime.utcnow()
            
        self.start = starttime
        self.fig = fig
        self.end = endtime
        self.axis_num = 1
        self.dates = mpl.dates.date2num(dates)
        #self.time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M UTC')
        #self.title = f'Latest Ob Time: {self.time}\nProbe ID: {probeid}'

    def plot_winds(self, ws, wd, wsmax, ax, plot_range=None):
        """
        Required input:
            ws: Wind speeds (knots)
            wd: Wind direction (degrees)
            wsmax: Wind gust (knots)
        Optional Input:
            plot_range: Data range for making figure (list of (min,max,step))
        """
        # PLOT WIND SPEED AND WIND DIRECTION
        self.ax1 = ax
        ln1 = self.ax1.plot(self.dates, ws, label='Wind Speed')
        plt.tight_layout()
        self.ax1.fill_between(self.dates, ws, 0)
        self.ax1.set_xlim(self.start, self.end)
        if not plot_range:
            plot_range = [0, 30, 5]
        self.ax1.set_ylabel('Wind Speed (knots)')
        self.ax1.set_ylim(plot_range[0], plot_range[1], plot_range[2])
        self.ax1.grid(b=True, which='major', axis='y', color='k', linestyle='-',
                      linewidth=0.5)
        ln2 = self.ax1.plot(self.dates, wsmax, '.r', label='Gust')

        ax7 = self.ax1.twinx()
        ln3 = ax7.plot(self.dates, wd, '.k', linewidth=0.1, label='Wind Direction')
        ax7.set_ylabel('Wind\nDirection\n(degrees)', multialignment='center')
        ax7.set_ylim(0, 360)
        ax7.set_yticks(np.arange(45, 405, 90), ['NE', 'SE', 'SW', 'NW'])
        
        
        lines = ln1 + ln2 + ln3
        labs = [line.get_label() for line in lines]
        ax7.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d'))
        ax7.legend(lines, labs, loc='center', bbox_to_anchor=(.9, -0.25), ncol=3, prop={'size': 12})
        
        

         
        

# ID For Plotting on Meteogram
probe_id = 'SOCA'

from calendar import monthrange
year = 2019

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=6, ncols=2, figsize=(140, 50))

for months in range(1, 13):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(200, 50)) 
    plt.tight_layout()
    a = monthrange(year, months)
    endtime = dt.datetime(2019, months, a[-1], 0, 0)
    starttime = dt.datetime(2019, months, 1, 0, 0)
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)
    df_new = df[(df['ICAO'] == probe_id) & (df['month'] == months)] #& (df['month'] == month) & (df['hour'] < 8) & (df['hour'] > 4)]
    df_new['wind_speed'] = pd.to_numeric(df_new['wind_speed'], errors='coerce')
    df_new['wind_dir'] = pd.to_numeric(df_new['wind_dir'], errors='coerce')
    df_new['wind_gust'] = pd.to_numeric(df_new['wind_gust'], errors='coerce')
    df_new['temp'] = pd.to_numeric(df_new['temp'], errors='coerce')
    df_new['dewpt'] = pd.to_numeric(df_new['dewpt'], errors='coerce')
    df_new['press'] = pd.to_numeric(df_new['press'], errors='coerce')
    df_new['wind_gust'] = df_new['wind_gust'].fillna(0) 

    meteogram = Meteogram(fig, df_new['datetime'], probe_id)
    #meteogram.plot_winds(df_new['wind_speed'], df_new['wind_dir'], df_new['wind_gust'])
    meteogram.plot_winds(df_new['wind_speed'], df_new['wind_dir'], df_new['wind_gust'], ax=axes[(months-1) % 6, (months-1) // 6])
    
 
fig = plt.figure() 
fig.savefig('test.png')
```

Comment: Note that each time you call `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))` you are abandon the current figure and creating a new empty one.  You could consider calling `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))` before the `for` loop starts, or put it at the start of the loop if you want 1 figure per month.

Comment: Thanks JohanC thats fixed the first issue :) 

I'm trying to understand why I can't save the entire figure to a single png ? I was thinking it's because I'm not declaring the add_subplot() correclty.

Comment: You are creating one plot per month.  To have multiple subplots, you can use `fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4, figsize=...)` before the `for` loop and inside use `meteogram.plot_winds(...., ax=axes[(months-1) % 4, (months-1) // 4])`. Inside `plot_winds` you need an `ax` parameter, and set `self.ax1 = ax` instead of creating a new one (so, avoid using `fig.add_subplot` there). Note the `s` at the end of `plt.subplots`, these functions have extremely similar names.

Comment: Figured it out! Any ideas why my axis labels for the y twinx aren't displaying at all? It almost looks like they are being trimmed away  ?

Comment: I'll give it a go, I still can't get it to save the figure. I keep printing blank files with this after the for loop.
 
fig.savefig('test.png')

Comment: Using the same `fig` as `fig, axes = plt.subplots(...)`? And without doing things such as `fig = plt.figure()`

Comment: I added an update into the above, I think it's an issue in it's position or me not knowing what the figure is called?

Comment: Please DON'T do `fig = plt.figure() `. That erases the figure.  You are calling this two times. You should never call it.  (You might call `fig = plt.gcf()`, but that is not needed as `fig` already has the desired value.)  Also, only call `plt.tight_layout()` at the end, not at the start.  You can also use `fig.savefig(...,  bbox_inches='tight')` to have a "tight" image when saved.